# In Python's Pip, how can you search for all possible versions of a package, which match a version pattern?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to build a support matrix of requirements in my project. I use the `~=` syntax to match minor versions, however because I'm packaging a PiPy client to corporate clients I really need to test all possible versions.

I know how to search for all versions of a PiPy package using the hack `pip install xyz==`, but I really want to know how to search for all compatible versions given a requirement string.

i.e what versions could possibly be installed (or won't conflict) for

```
pip install xyz<=10
```

Or

```
pip install xyz~=9.0.0
```

(Pip install rules are quite complex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While writing this question, I came up with this solution. Unfortunately it uses the internal Pip code, and I'm sure it can be can be condensed down, but it works with pip version 19.

```
from pip._internal.models.format_control import FormatControl
from pip._internal.download import PipSession
from pip._internal.index import PackageFinder
from pip._internal.req import InstallRequirement
from pip._vendor.packaging.requirements import Requirement


package_finder = PackageFinder(
    find_links=[],
    format_control=FormatControl(set(), set()),
    index_urls=['https://pypi.org/simple'],
    trusted_hosts=[],
    allow_all_prereleases=False,
    session=PipSession(),
)


def get_valid_versions(requirement_string, include_preleases=False):
    install_req= InstallRequirement(
        Requirement(requirement_string), comes_from=None
    )
    all_candidates = package_finder.find_all_candidates(install_req.name)
    return set(
        install_req.specifier.filter(
            [str(c.version) for c in all_candidates],
            prereleases=include_preleases,
        )
    )
```

Usage:

```
 >>> get_valid_versions('dask~=2.8.0')
 {'2.8.0', '2.8.1'}
```